# Always start app with a specific view (like SnapChat)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I want to always be on a certain view when the user enters the app.

So, like SnapChat, if I'm on the List view, when I re-enter the app, I want to be on the Camera view. This view needs to be displayed immediately as the app is displayed.

Things I've tried:

1. On `applicationDidEnterBackground:`/`applicationWillResignActive`/`applicationDidBecomeActive`: changing the self.window.rootViewController to my specific view works, but there is a 1-2 second delay, which just seems really sloppy.
2. "Application does not run in background" = "YES". I may need some things to be running in the background, so trying to avoid this solution.

Any help will be rewarded in unicorn tears. Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried changing the rootViewController in applicationWillResignActive??

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `applicationWillResignActive` instead of `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

It is called as part of your application's handling of events through processing the run loop, which only begins after `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`: has finished.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have tried `applicationWillResignActive`. It has the same effect as changing the view within `applicationDidEnterBackground`, ie. it updates the view but with a delay.

Comment: hmm, provide the code that you have used. do you have code like "animation:YES" ??

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works for me on iOS 9. Keep a reference of the controller which is linked to your destination view controller (in my case the `activityViewController` which has a segue to `snapViewController`). Then perform the segue to your destination view controller in `applicationDidEnterBackground`. This ensures that your app always starts with the `snapViewController`

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

         activityView?.performSegueWithIdentifier("snapNoAnimation", sender: activityView!)


    }
```